# Why does the Monero difficulty increase?

Tags: mining, cryptonight, hashrate, asic-mining, difficulty

Monero's difficulty has soared a lot in the last days and the trend seems to be confirmed.

Why did it happen? What is the technical reason?

Comment: A lot of useful answers to the title, but none to the body of the question. Why did the difficulty soar so fast in a few days? I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

> The difficulty is a numerical representation of how long on average it
>   will take to create a valid block that satisfies the Proof-of-Work
>   algorithm being used, it does not represent minutes or time per se.
>   but instead is an integer number that makes the PoW calculation take
>   longer to perform, this is adjusted by the nodes and miners so that on
>   average it ensures the network creates blocks at a generally
>   consistent rate. This is calculated among all the nodes and miners in
>   accordance with the globally agreed rules in the network, AKA
>   consensus rules. Miners that do not include this number in their
>   difficulty calculations will not have their block validated and
>   included by the rest of the network.

You can find the answer here: [Blockchain properties: what are Height and Difficulty?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/blockchain-properties-what-are-height-and-difficulty)

Answer (score 0):

Considering Monero's anti-ASIC algorithm，and Ethereum's hashrate ruduced in last days, may be the Ethereum miners turn to Monero.

Comment: https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/hashrate-eth-xmr.html ETH - hashrate not reduced this days.

Comment: Constantinople Ethereum Hard Fork is coming, the miners are looking for new roads.Past hashrate,not recent ones